# Minimally relaxing an infeasible linear program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to debug a piece of code to 'relax' an infeasible linear program formulated in the standard formulation

Program 1 (that we assume infeasible):

$max/min$ $c^{T}r \\
s.t. Ar  \leq, =, \geq  b\\
l \leq r \leq u$

The following problem would find the minimum set of relaxation on upper and lower bounds and constraints of problem 1 to make it feasible.

Program 2

$min$
$c^T r + \lambda ||v||_0 + \alpha (||p||_0 + ||q||_0) \\
  s.t.
       A r + v \leq, =, \geq  b \\
       l - p \leq r \leq u + q \\
       v \in R^m \\
       p,q \in R_+^n
$

Now my question is:

Does the solution to problem 2 ensure solely a minimal set of bounds and constraints to relax? e.g. variable 2 should be relaxed.

Or

Does problem 2 find a set of bounds and constraints to relax **and** the minimal set of adjustements on the those bounds and constraints to find a feasible LP? e.g. variable 2 should be relaxed by a minimum of 2 units.

Comment: Why should program 1 not be feasible? Take $l\leq r$ and $-u\leq -r$.

Comment: let's assume for a second that it isn't feasible given the bounds and constraints in Program 1 generally formulated.

Comment: First of all: _please do not use $\|\cdot\|_0$_. The cardinality function is not a norm. Use $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(\cdot)$ instead. And secondly---the cardinality function is not convex. So while yes, your does find a "minimal" relaxation in some sense of the term, it's also intractable, whereas the original problem was not.

Comment: You might also be interested in the notion of a "Minimum Irreducible Infeasible Subset". Your model above looks for the minimum number of constraints that must be deleted to make the problem feasible. An MIIS is different: it looks for the minimum number of constraints that _by themselves_ are infeasible. That is not the same thing!

Comment: thanks, this is interesting, would you have references about MIIS for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer would be that Program 2 finds the minimal cardinality solution without necessarily ensuring a minimal adjustement to the bounds andconstraints.